# JDeveloper Server Instance Domain is Invalid

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper

I am trying to start a server instance for the first time with JDeveloper and keep getting this error. I can't figure out how to fix it. When I run it, JDeveloper says that my domain is invalid. It regenerates and tries again, but then I get "The Server Instance cannot be started because the IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain was not built successfully." Please help >_<

The following is the error log.

```
Adding environment variable to WLST script USER_MEM_ARGS = -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
Log File:      C:\Users\tyton337\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.3.42.170820.0914\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_12.2.1.PATCHSETS_GENERIC_170820.0914.S
Product Home:  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\tyton337\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.3.42.170820.0914\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2018-06-03 20:42:55

cmd.exe /c ""C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\tyton337\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.3.42.170820.0914\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Process started
wlst > The system cannot find the file C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oui\bin\..\.globalEnv.properties.
wlst > ERROR: Unable to locate property "JAVA_HOME" in properties file C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oui\bin\..\.globalEnv.properties
wlst > 
wlst > Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
wlst > 
wlst > Jun 03, 2018 8:42:58 PM com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl init
wlst > SEVERE: Failed to get inventory for C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home
wlst > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.common.ReflectionHelper.process(ReflectionHelper.java:48)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.init(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:384)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.<init>(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:89)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.getInstance(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:364)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceFactory.getEnvironmentService(EnvironmentServiceFactory.java:35)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceFactory.getEnvironmentService(EnvironmentServiceFactory.java:72)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.init(WLScriptContext.java:303)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.setup(WLScriptContext.java:270)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLST_offline.setupContext(WLST_offline.java:46)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.initOfflineContext(WLSTUtil.java:514)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.setupOfflineInternal(WLSTUtil.java:488)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.setupOffline(WLSTUtil.java:361)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtilWrapper.setupOffline(WLSTUtilWrapper.java:29)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.<init>(WLSTInterpreter.java:250)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.WLST.main(WLST.java:134)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at weblogic.WLST.main(WLST.java:47)
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.InventoryException: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
wlst >  - with linked exception:
wlst > [java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory\distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.3.0.xml (Access is denied)]
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryImpl.<init>(OracleHomeInventoryImpl.java:55)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryFactory.createInventory(OracleHomeInventoryFactory.java:60)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.InventoryFactory.getOracleHomeInventory(InventoryFactory.java:99)
wlst >  ... 28 more
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
wlst >  - with linked exception:
wlst > [java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory\distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.3.0.xml (Access is denied)]
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.create(JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.java:127)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.parse(DaoHelper.java:173)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getRootWrapper(DaoHelper.java:401)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DistributionHelper.getDistribution(DistributionHelper.java:307)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DistributionHelper.getDistribution(DistributionHelper.java:290)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DistributionHelper.getDistribution(DistributionHelper.java:254)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.DistributionLoader.<init>(DistributionLoader.java:89)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.DistributionLoaderFactory.getDistributionLoader(DistributionLoaderFactory.java:45)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadInstalledDistributions(Home.java:1622)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadInstalledMetaData(Home.java:1209)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadHomeMetaData(Home.java:1190)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.refresh(Home.java:1131)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.setHome(Home.java:320)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.<init>(Home.java:288)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.getHome(Home.java:224)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.getHome(Home.java:187)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryImpl.<init>(OracleHomeInventoryImpl.java:50)
wlst >  ... 30 more
wlst > Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
wlst >  - with linked exception:
wlst > [java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory\distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.3.0.xml (Access is denied)]
wlst >  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:261)
wlst >  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
wlst >  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
wlst >  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
wlst >  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
wlst >  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.create(JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.java:118)
wlst >  ... 46 more
wlst > Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory\distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.3.0.xml (Access is denied)
wlst >  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
wlst >  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
wlst >  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
wlst >  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
wlst >  at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
wlst >  at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:623)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:805)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
wlst >  at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
wlst >  at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:171)
wlst >  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
wlst >  ... 52 more
wlst > 
wlst > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.initOfflineContext(WLSTUtil.java:514)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.setupOfflineInternal(WLSTUtil.java:488)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.setupOffline(WLSTUtil.java:361)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtilWrapper.setupOffline(WLSTUtilWrapper.java:29)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.<init>(WLSTInterpreter.java:250)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.WLST.main(WLST.java:134)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at weblogic.WLST.main(WLST.java:47)
wlst > Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceException: Failed to get inventory for C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.init(WLScriptContext.java:353)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.setup(WLScriptContext.java:270)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLST_offline.setupContext(WLST_offline.java:46)
wlst >  ... 15 more
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceException: Failed to get inventory for C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.init(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:425)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.<init>(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:89)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.getInstance(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:364)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceFactory.getEnvironmentService(EnvironmentServiceFactory.java:35)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceFactory.getEnvironmentService(EnvironmentServiceFactory.java:72)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.init(WLScriptContext.java:303)
wlst >  ... 17 more
wlst > Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.common.ReflectionHelper.process(ReflectionHelper.java:48)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.init(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:384)
wlst >  ... 22 more
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.InventoryException: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
wlst >  - with linked exception:
wlst > [java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory\distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.3.0.xml (Access is denied)]
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryImpl.<init>(OracleHomeInventoryImpl.java:55)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryFactory.createInventory(OracleHomeInventoryFactory.java:60)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.InventoryFactory.getOracleHomeInventory(InventoryFactory.java:99)
wlst >  ... 28 more
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
wlst >  - with linked exception:
wlst > [java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory\distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.3.0.xml (Access is denied)]
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.create(JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.java:127)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.parse(DaoHelper.java:173)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getRootWrapper(DaoHelper.java:401)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DistributionHelper.getDistribution(DistributionHelper.java:307)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DistributionHelper.getDistribution(DistributionHelper.java:290)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DistributionHelper.getDistribution(DistributionHelper.java:254)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.DistributionLoader.<init>(DistributionLoader.java:89)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.DistributionLoaderFactory.getDistributionLoader(DistributionLoaderFactory.java:45)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadInstalledDistributions(Home.java:1622)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadInstalledMetaData(Home.java:1209)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadHomeMetaData(Home.java:1190)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.refresh(Home.java:1131)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.setHome(Home.java:320)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.<init>(Home.java:288)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.getHome(Home.java:224)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.getHome(Home.java:187)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryImpl.<init>(OracleHomeInventoryImpl.java:50)
wlst >  ... 30 more
wlst > Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
wlst >  - with linked exception:
wlst > [java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory\distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.3.0.xml (Access is denied)]
wlst >  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:261)
wlst >  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
wlst >  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
wlst >  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
wlst >  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
wlst >  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.create(JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.java:118)
wlst >  ... 46 more
wlst > Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory\distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.3.0.xml (Access is denied)
wlst >  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
wlst >  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
wlst >  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
wlst >  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
wlst >  at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
wlst >  at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:623)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:805)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
wlst >  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
wlst >  at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
wlst >  at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:171)
wlst >  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
wlst >  ... 52 more
wlst > Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
wlst > 
wlst > Type help() for help on available commands
wlst > 
wlst > Creating Default Domain
wlst > [progress] Reading template: Basic WebLogic Server Domain
wlst > Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
wlst >   File "C:\Users\tyton337\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.3.42.170820.0914\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py", line 35, in ?
wlst >   File "C:\Users\tyton337\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni5486373371019476072.py", line 53, in setTopologyProfile
wlst >   File "C:\Users\tyton337\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni5486373371019476072.py", line 19, in command
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:721)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst > 
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst > java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
wlst > 
wlst > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Elapsed time:  5377 ms
```

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution? I'm running into the same issue and it looks like the proximate cause is: "wlst > The system cannot find the file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oui\bin\..\.globalEnv.properties."  Even though the properties file is in the correct directory.  In fact, I've tried copying it at each level of the path.

Answer (score 1):

please make sure you have full permission to access globalEnv.properties and other file.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Jdeveloper as an Admin

Answer (score 0):

Running JDeveloper as **administrator** resolved the issue for me.